# Check sent $_POST size

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, post

I'm working on a Codeigniter application that can be accessed via Smartphones. The thing is that, at least for my carrier, the application won't load because of a "server" error (according to a 5.0 Blackberry Browser, POST data sent too big or GET data received too big, and a 6.0 Blackberry Browser, "The requested URL could not be retrieved - sorry, the file you're trying to upload or download is too large"). The strange thing is that, when connected to a WiFi network, the site starts working again flawlessly.

I was wondering if I could mesure the PHP POST data sent and received in MB / KB, so I can slim it down as much as I can.

I don't know if this is a Codeigniter issue, or a carrier issue, or both, because the error appears only when I pass data via the URL. For example

example.com/codeigniter/main - OK
example.com/codeigniter/main/post/131 - boom, dead.

Being "codeigniter/" the application, "main/" the controller, "post/" the method and 131 the value.

I'm using Codeigniter Reactor 2.0.1, BTW.

Comment: What do the HTTP Headers look like?

Comment: @jnpcl The HTTP headers are huge, now that I see them. Not ACTUALLY huge, but more than I tought they would be. This is the main GET HTTP Set_cookie: http://sharetext.org/SN4 - I'm figuring that this might not be the best way to set cookies in CI (if there's another one). There are other 5 "Cookie" HTTP requests like this one: http://sharetext.org/SN5. Although it's just 73kb. Could that be it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to measure the size of the request, the $_SERVER superglobal has a property for this.

```
  $size = (int)$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
```

Submit your post to an endpoint with this code and echo it's value.

This will assign the value of the Content-length HTTP header to $size if the request was sent via the POST method.

Comment: This does answer the question yet not solves the problem per se (because the error is confusing - it says that maybe the POST is too big or the GET is too big, but there are neither in actual use). Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: @AeroCross: I'm going to guess that you're storing way too much in your cookie. Keep it under 4KB for compatibility's (and sanity's) sake.

Comment: @jnpcl You're guessing wrong - I'm storing only 1.2 KB in the cookie (and you know that CI stores a lot of stuff aside the user-defined data). The thing is that, from what I've been testing, that long, long header is the result of several $this->session->set_userdata() calls (4, in total). Codeigniter seems to be overwriting over and over again the data it holds for each $this->session->set_userdata() call. In the other GET requests, only one is showing - the actual cookie.

Comment: @AeroCross: I was basing my comment on the link you posted (http://sharetext.org/SN4) -- that page is just under 30KB of data.